# Javascript get coordinates of visible part of background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div lets say

```
<div class="cover"></div>
```

with a background image lets say

```
.cover{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  background: url("../../../static/talentapp/images/cover.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

The image is 1000px by 600px so there are hidden parts of the image.
How do I use JavaScript to get the coordinates of the visible part of the image? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please make an attempt at this first, there are plenty of resources on Google on how you can get started.

Comment: @Alex why don't you throw in some pointers. I have searched Google and didn't find any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('cover')[0];
a.addEventListener('click',function(e){
var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
alert("X Coordinate: " + x + " Y Coordinate: " + y);
})
```

```css
.cover{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb") no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover"></div>
```